# Adding Odbc reference to my application

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to connect to MySql database using ODBC. I am unable to find reference for System.Data.Odbc in my project. I keep on getting this exception

```
 System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionHandle..ctor(OdbcConnection connection, OdbcConnectionString constr, OdbcEnvironmentHandle environmentHandle)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionOpen..ctor(OdbcConnection outerConnection, OdbcConnectionString connectionOptions)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningCo
nnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, Db
ConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions use
rOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open()
   at DbConnection.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\ankur_agrawal\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\DbConnection\Program.cs:line 17System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an ope
n and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.SetStateExecuting(String method, OdbcTransaction transaction)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ValidateConnectionAndTransaction(String method)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
```

The code I have written is

```
namespace DB
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Program p = new Program();
                OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=localhost;USER=root;PASSWORD=root;DATABASE=employee");
                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("select * from emplpoyee", con);
                con.Open();
                OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which MySQL version you are using? You have to use `Driver` part? [This link](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) suggest uses like `Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 UNICODE Driver}` or `Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver}`

Comment: Did that,still getting exception

Comment: Did you install this http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WINDOWS-8 , you will have problem to connect to MYSQL DB .. to solve this issue you should run the visual studio to be compatible with Win7.